# Calculating Overlapping Points in Sequences Generated from Lists of Integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, integers

**Problem:**

I have encountered a problem related to sequences generated from lists of integers, and I am seeking a method to calculate whether these sequences will ever overlap. This problem can be described as follows:

I have two lists of integers, for example:

- List 1: {16, 4}
- List 2: {12, 5}

Each list creates a sequence by adding the integers iteratively. For instance:

- List 1 sequence: 16 (+16), 20 (+4), 36 (+16), 40 (+4), ... , 200 (+4), 216 (+16)
- List 2 sequence: 12 (+12), 17 (+5), 29 (+12), 34 (+5), ... , 204 (+5), 216 (+12)

I want to determine whether these two sequences will ever overlap, and if so, at which point they overlap.

**Other examples:**

- List 1: {17, 8}
- List 2: {8, 9}

> They overlap at a number: 42

- List 1: {52, 4}
- List 2: {60, 12}

> They overlap at a number: 276

- List 1: {16, 4}
- List 2: {19, 5}

> They don't overlap

**Specific questions:**

1. What mathematical approach can be used to calculate whether two sequences will overlap?
2. Is there a general formula or method to determine if there is an overlap and to find the overlapping point?
3. How can this problem be extended to handle multiple values in two or more lists and calculate if they overlap?

Comment: Do you consider the two sequences overlapping if the common term appears at different indices?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: In that case, all sequences must overlap. Even $\{19,5\}$ and $\{16,4\}$ overlap at 120